# Authorizing user for further part but if info is wrong notify him that his/her acc is deleted

Tags: django, django-models

I'm new to the Django framework. after the user is logged in user fills a form and that data is sent to admin which can be done through `modelform`. what I actually want to do is this data should be viewed by the admin and if the info provided in the form is wrong/misguided then the admin deletes his/her account notifying him to fill the valid info in the form. How can it be done?

Comment: so do you want the Admin to view all of the forms that have been submitted, and then being able to delete them through a button or something?

Comment: Yes, but the user should get a notification that its acc is deleted.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you could do is create a model form, for the newly registered users.

Maybe something like this. So:

Let's assume you already have a model for the list of users. You could use AbstractUser Model like so:

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser

class User(AbstractUser):
    pass
```

You could create a model for newly registered users like :

```
class NewlyRegistered(models.Model):
    username = models.CharField( max_length=50)
    email = models.CharField( max_length=50)
    password = models.CharField( max_length=50)
    beendeleted = models.BooleanField()

    def serialize(self):
        return {
            "id": self.id,
            "user":self.user.username,
            "password": self.password
            "email":self.email
        }
```

let's say this is your python to register a new user, you could include in this function the creation of a NewlyRegistered user:

```
def register(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
    
        username = request.POST["username"]
        email = request.POST["email"]

        # Ensure password matches confirmation
        password = request.POST["password"]
        confirmation = request.POST["confirmation"]
        if password != confirmation:
            return render(request, "MyApp/register.html", {
                "message": "Passwords must match."
            })

         # Attempt to create new user
        try:
            user = User.objects.create_user(username, email, password)
            user.save()
        except IntegrityError as e:
            print(e)
            return render(request, "MyApp/register.html", {
                "message": "Email address already taken."
            })
        login(request, user)

        #HERE YOU CREATE THE NEW OBJECT FOR THE MODEL: 

        newregistered = NewlyRegistered.objects.create(username=username, email=email, 
        password=password)

        newregistered.save()

        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse("index"))
    else:
        return render(request, "MyApp/register.html")
```

And then you could create a template that only shows if the Admin is logged in, that displays all of the NewlyRegistered Objects, with then a button connected to another view function to delete that newly registered user, and using the "username" value you could also delete the User model! (which is what I understand you wanted to do)

With something like this, saying that you could for example pass the username in a slug:

```
def deleteuser(request, username):

   usertodelete = User.objects.filter(username=username).first()
   usertodelete.delete()
  #and then activating the boolean for the Newlyregistered
   newlydeleted = NewlyRegistered.objects.filter(username=username).first()
   newlydeleted.beendeleted = True
```

or however, you want to design it.

Lettin then the user know that his account has been deleted is a matter of creating an if statement in the log-in page function, that if the user that is trying to log in, is between the NewlyRegistered with the boolean field on True, then it has been deleted.